# ¿Se puede usar la misma etiqueta de reescritura en varios tipos de publicaciones en wordpress?

Tags: php

Por alguna razón, el fragmento solo funciona para un tipo de publicación.

```
function register_posts() {
$args = array(
       'public'    => true,
       'label'     => __( 'Books', 'textdomain' ),
       'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-book',
       'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'%store_name%')
   );
   register_post_type( 'book', $args );

$two_args = array(
       'public'    => true,
       'label'     => __( 'Product', 'textdomain' ),
       'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-product',
       'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'%store_name%')
   );
   register_post_type( 'product', $two_args );


add_rewrite_tag('%store_name%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_posts' );



function set_post_link( $post_link, $post ) {
   
       $post_type = $post->post_type;
       $author_id = $post->post_author;
       $store_name = get_user_meta($author_id,'store_name',true);
  

if  ($post_type === 'product' || 'book' === $post_type){
if (isset($store_name) && !empty($store_name)){
         
           $post_link = str_replace('%store_name%', $store_name , $post_link );
       }}
       
       
   return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'set_post_link', 10, 2 );
```

Esto funciona solo para "libro", y solo si elimino este cpt funcionará para "producto". Pero necesito ambos enlaces permanentes para usar la misma variable.

Probé varios fragmentos y encontré varias respuestas a problemas similares, pero ninguna para varios tipos de publicaciones.

Además probé cambiar la etiqueta para el segundo tipo de publicación y añadir la etiqueta de reescritura correspondiente pero no me funciona tampoco. Solamente puedo reescribir un tipo de publicación y no encuentro documentación sobre como hacer para varios.